# Using object in controller

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have a function that returns the raw result of a query as an object. So this:

Items.php

```
public static function getItems($item){

$sql = "
        SELECT count(*) as items from itemTable where itemNumber = {$item};
    ";

    $result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));

    return $result;
}
```

Which, when dumped directly, returns the object:

```
"items":15
```

The problem is, I'm accessing this in the controller and when I try to dump "$items" on the blade it is null

Conroller:

```
$itemFile = new Items();
$items= $itemFile->getItems($item);

return view('test.blade')
    ->with('items', $items);
```

Blade:

```
dd($items);
```

But if I put

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT count(*) as items from itemTable where itemNumber = {$item}"));
dd($results);
```

Then I get the object above at the blade.

How can I properly pass this into the blade

Comment: Can you show your contrller code?

Comment: Just updated with more controller code

Comment: Can you show what items class contain please and what does `$item` variable hold? Sorry its little confusing.

Comment: in my class file, if I use ```dd($result)``` instead of return $result then it dumps on the page

Comment: It's updated now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First suggestion to clean up your Item class :

```
<?php 

public static function getItemCount($item){

    //  Using PDO binding to avoid SQL injections
    $result = DB::select('SELECT count(*) as itemCount from itemTable where itemNumber = :item', [ 'item' => $item ]);

    return $result[0]->itemCount;
}
```

`DB::select()` returns an array even if you are using a count query. So I am u sing `[0]` index

Then in your controller :

```
$itemCount = (new Items())->getItemCount($item);

return view('test.blade', compact('itemCount'));
```

Then you will have variable `{{ $itemCount }}` ready to use

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your variable to blade like below code:

```
view( "your.blade.view", [ "items" => $items ] );
```

Or second method:

```
View::Share( 'items', items );
```

Comment: I am passing it to the blade, perhaps I misspoke. I just updated my question. The issue is that it's dumping null so I'm trying to figure out why I can't access it properly

Comment: Could you test for getting count by **$count = DB::table('itemTable')->count();** ?

Comment: but that's a count of everything in the table, right?

Comment: Yes, you can put **->where('itemNumber', '=', $item)** before **->count()** .